# Styling Elements that have been appended using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have div elements that  are appended on a parent div. Depending on the screen size, the div elements should resize but my efforts to do so using jquery .css() are failing all through. Kindly help. Below is a sample of my code

```
var len = data.length; //a number comes here
var i;
for(i=1;i<len+1;i++){
    $(".app-body").append(
       "<div class='list-box' onclick='OpenHymn("+ i +")'>" +
       "<div class='circle-text'><div class='hym_num'>" + i + "</div></div>" +
       "</div>");
}
//calling the function that should resize the divs
GridBoxes();

function GridBoxes(){
    var width=window.innerWidth;
    var divisible=parseInt(width-40);
    var size=divisible/4;
    var boxes=$('.list-box');
    boxes.css("width",size+"px");
    boxes.css("height",size+"px");
```

}

Comment: style using media queries in css

Comment: `div`s need to be positioned or displayed as else than `static` to apply `width` or `height` styles on them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the function inside `$(window).resize()` for it to fire everytime the window is resized

Code:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
  GridBoxes();
})
```

[**Example**](http://codepen.io/Ayeetu/pen/yeYgzZ?editors=101)

**You should really use media query's for this kind of problem.**

Comment: The resize() works very well. Great thanks. I will apply the media queries

Answer (score 0):

try this

```js
window.addEventListener("resize", GridBoxes);//called on window resize
var len = 4; //changed to a number here for testing
var i;
for(i=1;i<len+1;i++){
    $(".app-body").append(
       "<div class='list-box' onclick='OpenHymn("+ i +")'>" +
       "<div class='circle-text'><div class='hym_num'>" + i + "</div></div>" +
       "</div>");
}
//calling the function that should resize the divs
//GridBoxes();

function GridBoxes(){
    var width=window.innerWidth;
  
    var divisible=parseInt(width-40);
    var size=divisible/4;
  
    var boxes=$('.list-box');
  for(var b=0;b<boxes.length;b++){
   
    boxes[b].css("width",size+"px");
    boxes[b].css("height",size+"px");
    }

}
```

```css
.list-box{border:1px solid red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="app-body"></div>
```